# mediawiki move upload path error

Tags: php, mediawiki

In mediawiki,localsettings.php, I just defined the upload directory as `$wgUploadDirectory = "/uploads";` .The file will be uploaded in this folder. but the problem is  it will automatically create a folder like `uploads/4/4a`.so we cant retrieve the file path correctly. please suggest me any solution to define the path and to retrieve file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path "uploads/4/4a" bothers you, and you would rather have everything in "uploads/", you can also set `$wgHashedUploadDirectory = false;` in your LocalSettings.php to achieve this.

Cf. the [manual page for $wgHashedUploadDirectory](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgHashedUploadDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

You will never need the direct path, because mediawiki has it's own linking inside.
First you upload whatever you want and then you link to it by the name you gave it.

```
[[File:yourname.png]]
```

after your upload, the file has the name you gave it at upload.  You can always check it when you go to `www.yourwiki.com/index.php/Special:ListFiles`

or manually visit `special Pages` then go for `file list`

[image: files uploaded]

Under Column Name  you will find your filename, and then just link to it, as shown above.

Check this site [How to link in mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links)